# Java cannot insert data into Mongo

Tags: java, mongodb

I am currently having an issue where I am trying to use insertOne to insert id of 1 and name as John Smith into my MongoDB collection. I have no errors when running however when going into my collection I cannot see any data being created. Any idea why this is happening and a possible solution please?

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;

public class Main {
    private static Player playerOne;
    private static Player playerTwo;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MongoClient client = MongoClients.create("mongodb+srv://testUser:Minal1171!abc@cluster0.s2mbq.mongodb.net/chosenWord?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
        MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("chosenWord");
        MongoCollection col = db.getCollection("words");
        Document sampleDoc = new Document("_id", "1").append("name", "John Smith");
        col.insertOne(sampleDoc);

        new Game();
    }
}
```

Comment: insertOne returns the results of the insert, its a class InsertOneResult, see the contents, it might help you. [see](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.1/apidocs/mongodb-driver-core/com/mongodb/client/result/InsertOneResult.html?is-external=true)

Comment: sorry what do you mean by this? I have done some research and they suggest using this InsertOne method

Comment: insertOne returns and object with information, save the result of insert and print it

Comment: Hi please read this code: Document document = new Document();
        document.append("name", "minal");
        //inserting the document into the collection
        database.getCollection("words_new").insertOne(document);
        System.out.println("Document inserted successfully");

Comment: The above code I just posted on the comment is not printing anything when I run the application

Comment: i mean `InsertOneResult result = col.insertOne(sampleDoc);` and print the contents of the result, to see what happened.

Comment: I just did this and getting this exception now Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@71bbf57e.

Comment: i think its related to your connection string, or the mongodb process. Does'nt look like insertOne related problem. This timeout means it can't communicate with database => timeouts